# Matlab neural network tool box,on extract weight & bias from feedforwardnet

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My problem is simple. I have trained a feedforwardnet. now I want to extract its weights and biases so i can test it on another programming language. but while i tested those trained weights by my own code, it always returns different results compare with neural tool box.here is my code

```
close all 
RandStream.setGlobalStream (RandStream ('mrg32k3a','Seed', 1234));
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
plot(t)
hold on 
topo = [2]
net = feedforwardnet(topo);
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
plot(y)

%rewrite net

BI = net.B{1};
WI = net.IW{1};

BO = net.B{2};
WO = net.LW{2};

% input layer

Z = WI*x + BI*ones(1,length(x));
Z = 2./(1+exp(-2*Z))-1;

Y = WO*Z + BO*ones(1,length(x));

plot(Y)
legend('target','tool box result','my result')
```

it is a simple neural network only have two layer.
no scaling or normalization be implied
here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural network inputs and outputs are mapped to the `[-1;1]` range by default, so the calculation of `Z` and `Y` is correct for the mapped values, not for the actual inputs and outputs. To avoid this, you can unset the `processFcns` properties:

```
 ....
net = feedforwardnet(topo);
net.inputs{1}.processFcns= {};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns= {};
net = train(net,x,t);
 ....
```

Alternatively, you can map the input and output values manually:

```
x= mapminmax(x,-1,1);
Z = WI*x + BI*ones(1,length(x));
Z = 2./(1+exp(-2*Z))-1;
Y = WO*Z + BO*ones(1,length(x));
Y= mapminmax(Y,min(y),max(y));
```

Comment: hi, I am a little confuse on matlab scaling input ... Since matlab neural network tool box uses scaled(to range [1,-1]) features and targets as learning input, and 'scale back' (to original size) the learning output as return.but to 'scale back' it requires us to know the actual MAX and MIN value,it is makes sense for train data(we know our original Target). what happens for test/predict part where we dont have MAX and MIN value...