# Manually do forward calculation for neural network trained in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, pattern-recognition

I'm training a neural network in Matlab using the built-in toolbox. I use dataset `iris` and put 10 hidden units for the hidden layer. The architecture of the network is quite simple, one input (size=4), one hidden (size=10) and one output (size=3).

After training, I can see the result is pretty good via the confusion matrix.
Now I want to extract the weight matrices from the trained network. I use the following commands:

```
w1 = cell2mat(net.IW);
w2 = cell2mat(net.LW);
b1 = cell2mat(net.b(1));
b2 = cell2mat(net.b(2));
```

Now I want to do forward calculation manually. From the variable `net` saved in Matlab environment, I know the transfer functions are `tansig` and `softmax`. I use following commands:

```
B1 = repmat(b1,1,150);
A1 = tansig(w1*irisInputs + B1);
B2 = repmat(b2,1,150);
A2 = softmax(w2*A1 + B2):
[~,classes] = max(A2);
```

However, I can see the result `classes` contain a lot of wrong classifications. I find it confusing because the confusion matrix shows a very good result (~99%).
If I use the Matlab function:
`ouput = net(irisInputs)`, I get the same results as what drawn by the confusion matrix.
What's gone wrong here?

Comment: It is because of the input mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837406/matlab-neural-network-tool-box-on-extract-weight-bias-from-feedforwardnet/40841392

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that they use normalization. Thanks.